# Unable to select ArcGIS layout boxes (created with Insert Picture) after path changed?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I inserted a few png images into my map layout (state road shields), but when I changed the path for the folder they were located in, they no longer appear. The problem is that a box has appeared that is not selectable, and I cannot delete it.

Attached is a picture showing two yellow boxes "481px-Florida_281.svg". Is there a way to remove these. I have re-added the images to the map, but the box still remains.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That beige box with the filename in it **is** actually selectable, but for whatever reason you have to click in the center of the box (I'd guess about where the "da" in "Florida" is in the middle box in your screenshot) to select it. If you click where ".svg" is, for example, it won't register. That should work but depending on which of those graphic elements is on top of the others, it may be tricky. You could also select it by drawing a selection box around the whole beige box and dragging it outside the printable area.

Comment: Thank you Dan. That was driving me crazy, glad it was something so simple.

Comment: Sure. It **still** drives me crazy every time I encounter it, it's like ArcGIS just tosses all the rules of a GUI out the window.